# Letting keyboard shortcuts to take effect regardless of focused applications

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-mavericks

Keyboard shortcuts like `Command + Tab` take effect regardless of currently focused applications, but shortcut keys like "Move focus to active or next window" (`^F4` by default) are stolen by applications like Emacs or iTerm and do not work on such applications.

How does one make such keyboard shortcuts ("Move focus to active or next window" in my case) work generally regardless of which application you are on?

Comment: Maybe there's something useful [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=keyboard+shortcut+focus+is%3Aq)

Answer (score 0):

You can for example assign "Move focus to active or next window" to control-F19 and then use [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) to map control-F4 to control-F19:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F4, VK_CONTROL | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::F19, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Comment: hmm, didn't really work for me on keyremap4macbook...